# Meaning of _ in apply()

Tags: underscore.js

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15108250/356440), one of the answers code is:

```
var arrays = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2]];

_.map(_.zip.apply(_, arrays), function(pieces) {
     return _.reduce(pieces, function(m, p) {return m+p;}, 0);
});
```

in `apply(_, arrays)` I don't understand to what `_` is related.

Comment: _ is an object defined in underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/) ... my best guess, it's like $ for jQuery (except $ is used in many more) ... and must be a function object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) call is equivalent to

```
_.zip([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2])
```

The first argument to `apply` makes sure that `zip` is called with the right context ([`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) which usually is `_`, Underscore's namespace-[constructor-function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16378628/1048572)-object. Actually it's not used in the `zip` function, so we could've omitted it and passed `null` or `undefined` instead.

Comment: why don't you use  `_.partial(_.zip,arrays)`  ?

Comment: `_.partial` is for currying a function, which is not suitable here. It returns a function, not an array

Comment: @StephaneRolland: What for, instead of the `apply`? Because that doesn't invoke `zip`, calls it with the wrong arguments and doesn't return an array but a function. Check [what `_.partial` does](http://underscorejs.org/#partial).

Answer (score 1):

There is no much meaning in that `_`.

See the official page demo http://underscorejs.org/#zip

The main point here is `apply`, which accepts the second argument `arrays` as arguments.

So `_.zip(arr1, arr2, arr3)` is actually the same as `_.zip.apply( null,[arr1,arr2, arr3])`

The first argument, which acts as `this` keyword, can be anything. The choice of `_` is probably a meme and underscores the usage of `_`. Just follow it :)
[image]